# Record local audio in a docker container

Tags: ffmpeg, docker, alsa, pulseaudio

How can I record the audio of an application like Firefox inside a docker container with ffmpeg?
I've found examples how to forward pulseaudio to the host - [netflix](https://github.com/syncomm/dockerfiles/blob/master/netflix/), [skype](https://github.com/tomparys/docker-skype-pulseaudio).

When I'm trying to use pactl:

```
pactl list sources
```

Or

```
docker exec -it <container-id> bash
apt-get install pulseaudio
pactl load-module module-native-protocol-unix auth-anonymous=1 socket=/tmp/.pulse-socket
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

This also fail

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i default /tmp/pulse.wav
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a sound card in the docker container - pulse audio will create a null sink/source for you, and you can add a loopback device if you like as well.

However! I have gotten connection errors if I'm using a pulse audio library that needs X. I used Xvfb. And did something like this:

```
Xvfb :0 -screen 0 1600x1200x24+32 -ac -fbdir /shared_volume&
pulseaudio --start --disallow-exit -vvv --log-target=newfile:"$LOG_DIR/pulseaudio.log" --daemonize&
```

I just needed to detect when things were playing sound, but [this guide](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=110440) seemed a nice detailed coverage of how to use loopback devices to record stuff.

Answer (score 0):

By default you don't have access to the sound card inside the container. If you pass the `--privileged` flag to docker run, it should work. Note that this will give the container full privileges on the host, you might want to restrict this to a set of capabilities.

For more information: https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration

Comment: The host is a VPS so it doesn't have a sound card either. I'm interested in recording the audio with a virtual sound card similar to using a virtual frame buffer.

Comment: Well that changes things. No idea about virtual soundcards, but I still suspect it is a privileges issue.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688115/pactl-called-from-systemd-service-always-reports-pa-context-connect-failed-co but it looks like you might struggle to do this in Docker. It would make a good blog if you succeed.

Comment: I'm running pulseaudio manually with: "pulseaudio  --log-level=debug &"
Adding loopback with: "pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=mix
pactl load-module module-loopback sink=mix"
and recording with: "avconv -f pulse -i default /opt/recording /record.wav". It does record something but the sound is broken.